# How can I get self-closing tags in the output XML by using XslCompiledTransform?

Tags: xml, xslt, transform, xslcompiledtransform

Please help me...

I have input XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
    <Object>
      <GUID>201110180954525010129</GUID>
      <Meta name="FILENAME" format="string" frate="" />
    </Object>
</Root>
```

I need to transform it into the next xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root> 
    <Object> 
        <GUID>201110180954525010129</GUID>
        <FILENAME/> 
    </Object>
<Root>
```

I've created the next style sheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:element name="Root">

<xsl:for-each select="Root/Object">
<xsl:element name="Object">

<xsl:element name="FILENAME">
        <xsl:value-of select="Meta[@name='FILENAME']" />
</xsl:element>

<xsl:element name="GUID">
        <xsl:value-of select="GUID" />
</xsl:element>

</xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But when I trying to transform it, I get the next result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root> 
    <Object> 
    <GUID>201110180954525010129</GUID>
        <FILENAME> </FILENAME> 
    </MAObject>
<Root>
```

How can I tell to interpret self-closing tags ?

C# transformation code:

```
        var stylesheet = "styleSheet.xml";
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.Load("input.xml");
        XslCompiledTransform xslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
        xslTransform.Load(styleSheet);

            XmlDocument xmlDocumentOutput = new XmlDocument();
            XmlDeclaration xmlDocumentOutputDeclaration = xmlDocumentOutput.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);
            xmlDocumentOutput.AppendChild(xmlDocumentOutputDeclaration);

            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = xmlDocumentOutput.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
            {
                xslTransform.Transform(xmlDocument.CreateNavigator(), null, xmlWriter);
            }

            return xmlDocumentOutput;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried our samples with XslCompiledTransform, the output I get is

```
<Root>
  <Object>
    <FILENAME></FILENAME>
    <GUID>201110180954525010129</GUID>
  </Object>
</Root>
```

How do you run the transformation exactly, how do you look at the output? 
With XML an empty "foo" element can be marked up as `<foo></foo>` or `<foo/>` or `<foo />`, these forms are semantically equivalent. Why do you need a particular form? Is the output of the XSLT transformation not processed by an XML parser?

[edit]Try whether replacing

```
<xsl:element name="FILENAME">
        <xsl:value-of select="Meta[@name='FILENAME']" />
</xsl:element>
```

with

```
<FILENAME>
  <xsl:if test="normalize-space(Meta[@name='FILENAME'])">
    <xsl:value-of select="Meta[@name='FILENAME']"/>
  </xsl:if>
</FILENAME>
```

at least ensures the FILENAME element you get is empty.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. I've just updated the question... I really don't understand why I get white space between the tags 
<FILENAME> </FILENAME>

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the linebreaks (and any other whitespace) around `<xsl:value-of>` in the template that matches `FILENAME`. They are text nodes that show up in the result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will make any difference, but try this stylesheet, which has separate matching templates for the **Meta** with and without data. If nothing else, it is built on the identity template and so removes the need for hard-coding so many element names in your original XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="Meta">
      <xsl:element name="{@name}" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Meta[. != '']">
      <xsl:element name="{@name}">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I test this, I get the following result:

```
<Root>
   <Object>
      <GUID>201110180954525010129</GUID>
      <FILENAME/>
   </Object>
</Root>
```